# MySql calculate quantity

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**equipments**: `e_barcode , e_name, e_Quantity`

**equipments_booked**: `e_barcode (foreign key to equipments), employee_id`

I need a query to get the quantity of each equipment with the equipment id.
like this.

`e_barcode, e_available_quantity(not total)`

and the query that i have written is only showing me the available equipments:

```
SELECT * FROM `equipments` AS a
HAVING
a.`e_quantity` > (SELECT COUNT(`equipments_booked`.`e_barcode`) 
FROM `equipments_booked` WHERE `equipments_booked`.`e_barcode`=a.`e_barcode`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a join and aggregation:

```
SELECT e.bar_code, count(eb.e_barcode) as quantity_booked
FROM equipments e left join
     equipments_booked eb
     on e.e_barcode = eb.e_barcode
GROUP BY e.bar_code;
```

I'm not sure what the logic is behind your `having` clause.